# When i convert my numpy array to Dataframe it update values to Nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, imputation

```
import impyute.imputation.cs as imp

print(Data)
Data = pd.DataFrame(data = imp.em(Data),columns = columns)
print(Data)
```

When i do the above code all my values gets converted to Nan as below,Can someone help me where am i going wrong?

Before

```
     Time  LymphNodeStatus    ...      MeanPerimeter  TumorSize
0      31              5.0    ...             117.50        5.0
1      61              2.0    ...             122.80        3.0
2     116              0.0    ...             137.50        2.5
3     123              0.0    ...              77.58        2.0
4      27              0.0    ...             135.10        3.5
5      77              0.0    ...              84.60        2.5
```

After

```
     Time  LymphNodeStatus    ...      MeanPerimeter  TumorSize
0     NaN              NaN    ...                NaN        NaN
1     NaN              NaN    ...                NaN        NaN
2     NaN              NaN    ...                NaN        NaN
3     NaN              NaN    ...                NaN        NaN
4     NaN              NaN    ...                NaN        NaN
5     NaN              NaN    ...                NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Editted**

**Solution first**

Instead of passing `columns` to `pd.DataFrame`, just manually assign column names:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(imp.em(data))
data.columns = columns
```

**Cause**

Error lies in `Data = pd.DataFrame(data = imp.em(Data),columns = columns)`.

`imp.em` has a decorator `@preprocess` which converts input into a `numpy.array` if it is a `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
...
if pd_DataFrame and isinstance(args[0], pd_DataFrame):
    args[0] = args[0].as_matrix()
    return pd_DataFrame(fn(*args, **kwargs))
```

It therefore returns a `dataframe` reconstructed from a matrix, having `range(data.shape[1])` as column names.

And as I have pointed below, when `pd.DataFrame` is instantiated with *mismatching* `columns` on another `pd.DataFrame`, all the contents become `NaN`.

You can test this by

```
from impyute.util import preprocess

@preprocess
def test(data):
    return data

data = pd.DataFrame({"time": [1,2,3], "size": [3,2,1]})
columns = data.columns

data = pd.DataFrame(test(data), columns = columns))

size    time
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
```

When you instantiate a `pd.DataFrame` from an existing `pd.DataFrame`, `columns` argument specifies which of the columns from original dataframe you want to use.

It **does not** re-label the dataframe. Which is not odd, just the way `pandas` intended in [reindexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

> By default values in the new index that do not have corresponding records in the dataframe are assigned NaN.

```
# Make new pseudo dataset
data = pd.DataFrame({"time": [1,2,3], "size": [3,2,1]})
data
    size    time
0   3   1
1   2   2
2   1   3

#Make new dataset with original `data`
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["a", "b"])
data
a   b
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN
```

Comment: My column names are correct as i used Data.columns and used the result to store the column names in a list named 'columns'

Comment: Yes yes sure sorry didn't knew about that,my bad

Answer (score 0):

There may be some bug in `impyute` library. You are using `em` function which is nothing but a way to `fill-missing` values by `expectation-maximization` algorithm. You can try without using that function, as

`df = pd.DataFrame(data = Data ,columns = columns)`

You can raise this issue [here](https://github.com/eltonlaw/impyute/issues) after confirming. To confirm first load the data, using above example and find if there are null data present in the data by using `df.isnull()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data = pd.DataFrame(data = np.array(imp.em(Data)),columns = columns)
```

Doing this solved the issue i was facing, i guess the data after the use of `em` function doesn't return numpy array.